# to build cross platform async event based server that is working on windows and linux which lib to use?

Tags: c++, windows, event-handling

after reading this great [article](http://tinyclouds.org/iocp-links.html) im not sure how can i build simple cross platform server that can be has good as linux single event based servers . i didnt understand can it be done ? does boost aio is the right tool for this ? is there any other tool for this ?
im using c++ as the programming .

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned long* Internal;
  unsigned long* InternalHigh;
  union {
    struct {
      WORD Offset;
      WORD OffsetHigh;
    };
    void* Pointer;
  };
  HANDLE hEvent;
} OVERLAPPED;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also recommend the Adaptive Communication Environment http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html. But if you already use Boost in your existing code, `boost::asio` is a wonderful library to work with too.

Comment: hi ACE! i use it for dynamic service loading , i didn't know that this is a option at all . does ACE good for server building ?

Comment: Certainly. ACE abstracts away all minute details that you have to deal with in a cross platform way. Things such as epoll/select/IOCP is used transparently. It helps a lot in building socket-based applications.

Comment: Can you please recommend about beginners site for ACE networking

Comment: ACE authors made http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/ACE-tutorial.pdf. Prof Schmidt also explained clearly the patterns used in ACE http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/patterns-ace.html. Very worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, boost::asio is the right thing to go with.